# Jquery drag fires on mousemove but not on mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

So I'm using Jquery-ui's "draggable", and noticed something; the drag event only fires on mousemove. Now for the app I'm building, I need it to fire on mousedown as well as mousemove. To demonstrate what I mean, take a look at [this](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#cursor-style) example from Jquery-ui's website. The elements snap to a certain position relative to the mouse - but only when you've moved the mouse. I understand that this is not default behavior, but I need to simulate it. Let me explain my situation here;

I have a box with a circle in it. The user can drag the circle around the box, but the circle snaps to the cursor when the user mousedowns somewhere else in the box. Now, I have this:

```
    $('#big-box').mousedown(function(event){
        $('#tiny-circle').trigger(event);
    });
```

this makes sure the drag event is fired when the user mousedowns and mousemoves somewhere else in the box, but when the user clicks somewhere in the box, not on the circle, I need that circle to snap to the cursor. How do I go about doing this in a clean way? To illustrate what I mean; [Google's colorpicker](https://www.google.nl/search?q=colorpicker&rlz=1C1CHBD_enNL720NL720&oq=colorpicker&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.1868j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows my point exactly. You drag the circle around, but the circle snaps to the cursor when the user only clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after some experimenting I think this is as close I can get to a clean solution to the problem:

```
    $('#big-box').mousedown(function(event){
        $('#tiny-circle').css({left:event.offsetX,top:event.offsetY});
        $('#tiny-circle').trigger(event);
    });
```

and this works as intended.